# How to get remaining session time from CakePHP?

Tags: php, session, cakephp, timeout, cakephp-2.0

I could find the session timeout by using `Configure::read('Session.timeout');`. But i need the time remaining to expire the session,to display warning message just before the session  expires. Is there any way to do this?

**Update :** **CakePHP** version is 2.2.1  and **PHP** version 5.3.10

Answer (score 0):

Try to create another cookie with current date during initialization of user's session. You will have expiration time you need.

Then you can use CookieComponent:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html

to retrieve cookie and based on that you can show warning message to user. Simply calculate time that is left to expire the session.

Answer (score -1):

The _SESSION stays always until the client exits the website.